# How to perform ng-repeat on object returned from RESTful service

Tags: angularjs, rest, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a RESTful service that I'm calling to in order to return data. I've gotten the data object to return and can see the data from the constructed URL. Now I need to perform ng-repeat on that data and display in a div on submit. A little stuck. Here's my code.

I'm certain that it's something simple.

Many Thanks

(I've got proper dependencies)

```
<-- Service-->

var StoreUrl = configurationService.StoreUrl;

return {
    GetStore: function(StoreNum, City, State, StoreName, Zip) {
            console.log(StoreUrl + "/GetStoreList.ashx?StoreNumber=" + StoreNum + "&StoreCity=" + City + "&StoreState=" + State + "&StoreName=" + StoreName + "&ZipCode=" + Zip );
        return $httpq.get(StoreUrl + "/GetStoreList.ashx?StoreNumber=" + StoreNum + "&StoreCity=" + City + "&StoreState=" + State + "&StoreName=" + StoreName + "&ZipCode=" + Zip );
    }
};

<--Controller-->

$scope.StoreNumber = '';
$scope.StoreState = '';
$scope.StoreCity = '';
$scope.StoreName = '';
$scope.ZipCode = '';
$scope.stores = [];
$scope.getStores = function(){
storeLookupService.GetStores($scope.StoreNumber, $scope.StoreCity, $scope.StoreState, $scope.StoreName, $scope.ZipCode).then(function (result){
    if (result.StatusCode == "SUCCESS") {
        $scope.stores = result.stores;
    } else {
        alertify.alert(configurationService.ErrorMessage("finding stores", result.StatusMessage));
    }
});
};

<--View-->

<div class="col-lg-push-12 store-lookup">
        <form class="form-horizontal" name="storeLookup" >
            <label>Group Number:</label>
            <input  class="form-text" type="text" ng-model="StoreNumber" name="submitted[group]" id="edit-submitted-group">
            <label>Pharmacy Name:</label>
            <input class="form-text" type="text" ng-model="StoreName" name="submitted[store]" id="edit-submitted-store">
            <label>City:</label>
            <input  class="form-text" type="text" ng-model="StoreCity" name="submitted[city]" id="edit-submitted-city">
            <label>State: </label>
            <select id="state" class="form-control" ng-model="StoreState" ng-options="state.StateAbbr as state.StateName for state in StoreState" tabindex="15">
                <option value="">Pick a state</option>
            </select>
            <label>Zip:</label>
            <input class="form-text" type="text" ng-model="ZipCode" name="submitted[zip]" id="edit-submitted-zip">
            <label>24 Hour: </label>
            <input class="form-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="24hronly" id="edit-submitted-checkbox">
            <input id="edit-submit1" type="submit" value="Submit" ng-click="getStores()">

        </form>
    </div>
    <li class="storeresults" ng-repeat="store in Stores">{{store.StoreName}}</li>
```

The service returns an object structure like:

```
{"Stores":[{"StoreNum":"","StoreEmployerName":"","StoreName":"MK123","Address":"XXX","City":"XXX","State":"XX","Zip":"XXX","Phone":"(XXX) XXX-XXXX","Fax":"(XXX) XXX-XXX","Is24Hour":"0","Distance":"0","RecordNum":"1"}
```

Comment: I would look into using the resolve parameter of $routeParams - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider

Without seeing your routes, it's hard to give you a more concrete example, but the idea is that you would use the resolve method to call your RESTful service and inject the data into the controller so that it's available when the view is rendered.

Answer (score 1):

```
//Change this
$scope.stores = result.stores
//To This
$scope.Stores = result.Stores;
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all the suggestions. I actually had to call the object from the service along with the object from my service.

```
<li class="storeresults" ng-repeat="store in locationStores.Stores">{{store.StoreName}}</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in $scope.stores">
{{item.StoreNum}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do try the following,

```
<li class="storeresults" ng-repeat="store in controllername.stores">{{store.StoreName}}</li>
```

Because you are defining the object from the service as `"stores"` in the controller.